# Samba Server/Create Mask Isn't Right with New Folder Permissions

Tags: server, samba, directory

I have a quandry.

I've copied a section from my smb.conf, and also the permissions that actually appear when a user makes a new folder. Users aren't getting the permissions on folders that smb.conf's create mask should give.

Anywhere good to check? I've head disabling PAM restrictions fixes this, but what are the implications fo doing so (if that even IS the fix?)

I'm all muddled and stuff and very grateful for any help!

smb.conf says:
...
create mask = 0770
directory mask = 0770
...

Folder permissions look like:

drwxr-x--- user group ...

Answer (score 0):

I guess ext4? Take a look at umask and set the folder mask in ext4 to umask 000. By standard the umask is set to 022 what will course in you create a folder with permissions 777 and the mask will be substracted with 022 which than gives an effective folder permission of chmod 777 - umask 022 = 755.

If you now mask all folders on the partition or what ever you shared with the command "find /your/smb-share/point/ -type d -exec umask 000 {} \; than all folders will get the mask 000 in result if you create a folder with 777 it will be 777. Same for files. Command: "find /your/smb-share/point/ -type f -exec umask 000 {} \;

at the end to correct the broken existing permissions after umask "find /your/smb-share/point/ -type f -exec chmod 777 {} \;

That worked for me at least. You could find more information in the ubuntu help for umask and ext4 permissions.